Can a shock in certain circumstances be at a lesser angle than the Mach cone?

(Excuse the drawing quality)
What will happen if a shockwave has an angle less than that of the Mach cone?
In this picture, the black line represents the Mach cone. The orange line represents the shockwave angle that would be if it wasn't for the Mach cone making it be the same angle as the Mach cone itself. The yellow line is what this question is about.
So the shockwave can never be in front of the black line (like the orange one is). That's already established, here is an answer that explains it very well.
On a normal occasion, the shockwave would never be at the angle of the yellow line. Best stated from the answer linked above

The shock wave is therefore more "vertical" than the Mach cone

and that is always the case.

So now say that there is a shockwave at the angle of the black line and somehow it got bent past the angle of the Mach cone, just like the yellow line.

Picture of shockwave bending like linked answer above talks about.
If it bent the other way, I would understand how it would stay at the same angle as the Mach cone. But in this case, I don't see anything forcing the shock to be at the same angle as the Mach cone. To summarize, it makes sense why the shock wouldn't be at the angle of the orange line, but I don't see anything stopping it from being at the angle of the yellow line.

By "Certain Circumstances" I meant when the low pressure behind the object will bend the shockwave.
If I can improve this question in any way, please leave a comment. On that note, if the downvote was because this answer to my other question is too similar, I would understand but I don’t think it answers this specific question.

Downvoter, what here did I not follow correctly?

No.
Below is an oblique (2D, Wedge) shock chart.  It shows everything a 2D shock can do.
The top half of the chart is for strong shocks, the bottom half is for weak shocks.  Let's just deal with weak shocks for now.
Consider one value of $M_1$.  Say the $M_1=2.0$ line.  Notice where this line hits the Y-axis.  30 degrees.  For a deflection angle (x axis) of zero degrees.
This is the value of the Mach angle for $M=2.0$.  So, an infinitesimal disturbance that does not turn the flow at all will make a 30 degree shock with a $M=2$ upstream -- this is the definition of the mach cone.
Any flow turning (deflection angle non-zero) and the shock wave angle increases.

Here is the same sort of chart for a conical shock.
The values in this chart are different, but the general shape is the same.  Importantly, the place where a given Mach number intersects the axis is the same -- the Mach angle.
The differences in these charts are due to the 3D relieving effect of a cone.

You should look into NACA Report 1135 -- it is a great source for many compressible flow things.

I see. I understand that the shockwave angle will decrease with lower deflection angles (as stated in the graph), but since the Mach cone is purely a geometric entity, nothing could really change the angle of it besides speed. If the Mach cone stays constant, why does the shockwave not 'misalign' with the angles of it? Actually here is something I just thought of : Are you basically saying because there has to be a non 0 flow turning angle for a shock, and that the shock angle will always have to be greater than the Mach cone angle because of that?

Yes (to the last part).  Or, you could think of it this way -- an infinitesimally weak shock is at the Mach angle.  It does not turn the flow.  Any finite strength shock will be at a greater angle and will turn the flow.

Sorry to comment so long after you've answered, but I was curious about one thing: if the weakest possible shock is at the Mach cone angle, then wouldn't that mean a shock any stronger would have to be at a greater angle than the Mach cone? If so, wouldn’t that violate the rule that the shock angle always has to equal the Mach cone angle?

@Wyatt There is no rule that the shock angle equals the Mach cone angle.  You made that up.  Now that you've revisited an old question, perhaps you should select an answer.  You really should consider going back through all your questions and selecting answers -- some would consider it rude to keep asking questions and never identifying answers.  You aren't holding up your part of the Stack Exchange social contract.

To address the first part of your comment: I'm fairly confident of 2 things: 1. You can't hear an aircraft before the shockwave passes (If the shockwave doesn't travel forwards relative to the plane, neither does the sound) . 2. You can't hear the shockwave, a period of silence, and then the aircraft noise. If those are true, what other angle could the shockwave possibly be at than the Mach cone angle? (The link above is to this answer I just realized)

Second part: I do agree that I should mark answers as accepted, but sometimes I don't remember to click the little check mark. Now that you mention it, I will go through and mark the best answer as accepted. (and also try to make a habit of marking accepted answers) Also, the reason I just keep asking questions on this subject is because for some reason I can't seem to grasp this exact part.

I might just end up writing a question explaining everything I know / think about this subject so you and other people can see more clear where I am at. Typically my questions about shockwaves get downvoted a lot, so not sure if I should. (probably because I've asked quite a few shockwave questions, and people are tired of them)

I think you're just wrapping yourself around the axle...  The shockwave travels at the speed of the aircraft.  Say Mach 2.  The aircraft is supersonic, so no sound comes before the shock.  If you are an observer on the ground, you will hear the shock sometime after the aircraft has passed.   If the aircraft deflects the air 10 deg, the shock will be at 40 degrees.

When you talk about other aircraft noise, I presume you're talking about engine noise, or perhaps a loudspeaker on the airplane that is making a repeated beeping noise.  The sound from that beeper will travel at the speed of sound.  When combined with the forward speed of the aircraft, it will propagate at the Mach angle, in this case 30 degrees.  You will hear the boom first, and the beeping some time later.

Ah that would make sense. I was thinking that the shockwave itself always had to equal the Mach cone angle, but it doesn’t and that makes sense. The oblique shock chart kind of tells you that also. Thanks for helping me figure this out; it’s been confusing for quite some time. (Also, I will be going to mark accepted answers for all of my questions soon)
